# KDevelop and Cppcheck without active project

Tags: c++, cppcheck, kdevelop

Is it possible to somehow set cppcheck to run on regular c/c++ files without creating a project?
On my old computer cppcheck worked fine but now only works when I create a project in kdevelop.
I have no idea how to set it up again.

Kdevelop 5.6.2-3
Cppcheck 2.4.1-1
Arch linux
KDE Plasma 5.21.5

Comment: You can use Kate editor which allows you to run cppcheck on a file in a project(loaded folder).

Comment: Please post the error message you get when it does not work.